# When does checkout.session.completed trigger?

Tags: stripe-payments

The documentation for Stripe's `checkout.session.completed` is vague.

It says it `Occurs when a Checkout Session has been successfully completed.`

When does a checkout session complete? When a successful charge has been made?

Comment: Read https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders "Fulfill orders with Checkout" - for payment methods that are delayed, .completed is fired long before the payment succeeds or fails, read the section "Handle delayed notification payment methods"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> When does a checkout session complete? When a successful charge has
> been made?

Stripe emits the `checkout.session.completed` event each time one of your users successfully goes through the checkout flow:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed

The event won't be emitted if a user's payment fails, or if they fail to provide any of the required fields. There will however be other events (e.g., `payment_intent.payment_failed`) that will be emitted if you wanted to track failed attempts.

You can use the Stripe CLI to listen for all the events that are emitted to your account while running through the checkout flow with Stripe's [test cards](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards):

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli

Comment: So is it safe to assume that if `checkout.session.completed` fires, `payment_intent.succeeded` will also fire (not necessarily in the same order), and that there will be a one-to-one correspondence between these two events? (Although `payment_intent.succeeded` can also fire for other reasons other than a completed checkout session.) This is relevant because it affects how I structure the data recording these events.

Comment: @cazort https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#delayed-notification, it seems like completed will be fired first, then payment_intent.succeeded or payment_intent.payment_failed will be fired in depending on whether or not the payment have completed.

Comment: @cazort did you get the answer to your question? I am also not sure about which one to use and whether `checkout.session.completed` fires only if the payment intent succeeds.

Comment: Test this yourselves. I'm testing and don't even see a completed event if the payment is async, even after the async payment event fires.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if the payment succeeds, the `payment_intent.succeeded` will get fired and at the very next second the `checkout.session.completed` will get fired.

Note :- This is what happens when the entire payment is successful and the events will trigger in the above mentioned order.

You can refer to the types of events stripe handles -> https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types